# Can I use InternalsVisibleTo for C++ managed code?

Tags: c#, managed-c++, internalsvisibleto

I have C++ Managed project. And I'd like to test it with C# Nunit class library.
I defined C++ class as

```
internal ref class SomeClass{};
```

And how can I make it visible to C# class library?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, add the following to AssemblyInfo.cpp:

```
[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("C#UnitTestClassLibraryName")]
```

By the way, [**InternalsVisibleTo** works on the assembly level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279639/when-should-assembly-internalsvisibleto-be-used), so either the entire assembly is visible to the class specified, or none of it is.